# Solve $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac {e^{3x}-1}{e^{x}-1} $

Tags: limits

I have problem with  $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^{3x}-1}{e^{x}-1} $$
I have no idea what to do first.

Comment: L'Hopitals rule.. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353120/how-do-you-find-the-limit-of-lim-x-to-0-frac1-e6x1-e3x?rq=1) for a similar problem.

Comment: @Mattos There's a much more fundamental solution in the Answers section.

Comment: @FlybyNight And?

Comment: @Mattos : L'Hopital's rule is very efficient but often affords little or no insight. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sure, but the question title says _solve_.. So I gave a method to solve the problem.

Comment: . . . . . and "solve" is the wrong word.  One _solves_ problems; one _solves_ equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.  "Find" or "evaluate" would be appropriate.  There are a number of words in mathematics that, in the hands of the inexperienced, get used whenever they don't know which word to use, and "solve" is one of those. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Whether the OP said 'evaluate' or 'solve' is totally irrelevant to my suggestion to use l'Hopitals rule. I don't know why either you or Fly by Night commented to me at all.

Answer (score 20):

without using L'Hopital's rule

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{3x}-1}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(e^x-1)(e^{2x}+e^x+1)}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{2x}+e^x+1=3$$

Comment: I changed $lim{x\to0}$ to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 13):

**Hint** Recognize $e^{3x}-1$ as a difference of cubes.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 9):

HINT: Note that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: Great answer, and no need for L'Hopital's Rule. Perhaps use a different variable than the one already in use in the original question? For example $y^3-1 \equiv (y-1)(y^2+y+1)$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**
Use [equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis):
$$\mathrm e^{ax}-1\sim_0 ax,\quad\text{hence}\quad \frac{\mathrm e^{ax}-1}{\mathrm e^x-1}\sim_0 \frac{ax}x=a.$$

**Alternative hint:**
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{ax}-1}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}(\mathrm e^{ax})'\,\Big\lvert_{x=0}$$

Comment: This answer needs more explanation. I know about limits, but don't really understand what you're doing here. What does $\sim_0$ mean? How is the limit of the fraction
$$\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ax}-1}{x}$$
related to the derivative of $\mathrm{e}^{ax}$?

Comment: @Fly by Night: The problem is with the first hint?

Comment: This answer does not need to be improve, everything is crystal-clear. Besides, the OP has shown no effort. @FlybyNight there is no need to be aggresive.

Comment: @ClementC. If you hover your mouse over "add a comment", what does the pop-up say?

Comment: @ClementC. Your links were very helpful. But my comment was directed at the poster of this answer to improve his post. I thought you where him. That was my mistake. I suppose that you could edit his original and add your links? I'll be deleting my comments because they aren't relevant to the discussion. Take care.

Comment: @Clement C. : Sometimes, people are really aggressive on this site… Anyway, I only wrote hints, not a full solution.

Comment: @Bernard The problem was that your "hint" was very hard to understand. As someone not able to evaluate the original limit, one would find words like "equivalents" and symbols like $\sim_0$ very hard to understand. The truth is that *I don't know what they mean*. Like I said: your post would be improved by adding more explanation.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for adding the links and explainations. It's a much better answer now. **+1**

Comment: @Fly by Night: I've added a link (different from Clement C's, more specifically about equivalence) hopefully useful about this important notion in analysis.

Comment: @Bernard That's great, thank you!

Comment: (Since this is no longer relevant, and of little interest to anyone, I'll remove my comments :) )

Answer (score 5):

Let's apply [L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) here; i.e.,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^{3x}-1}{e^{x}-1}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac {3e^{3x}}{e^{x}}=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]3\,.$$

**OR** We can try substitution if you're not familiar with L'H rule:

$$t=e^x\Rightarrow \color{blue}{t\rightarrow1 \: as \: x\rightarrow0} \: \Rightarrow\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^{3x}-1}{e^{x}-1}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac {t^3-1}{t-1}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac {(t-1)(t^2+t+1)}{t-1}=\lim_{t\to 1}(t^2+t+1)=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]3$$
[image]

What you see above is the graph of $y=\frac{t^3-1}{t-1}$. As you can see it is not defined at $t=1$, but it has a limit that is equal to $3$ at $t=1$.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is often very efficient but often gives little or no insight.

Comment: I agree, that's why I provided OP with another way to solution.

Comment: Why do you put the sentence-ending period at the beginning of the next line after the sentence ends?  I fixed that in an edit, but then you changed it back.

Comment: I did not realize. You're free to edit again if it bothers you.

Answer (score 4):

My first thought was to write it as
$$
\frac{\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^{3x}-e^{3\,\cdot\,0}}{x-0} \right)}{\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^x-e^0}{x-0} \right)} = \frac{\left.\dfrac d {dx} e^{3x} \,\right|_{x=0}}{\left.\dfrac d {dx} e^x \,\right|_{x=0}} = \text{etc.}
$$

But the simpler way is to write $e^{3x}-1 = (e^x-1)(e^{2x}+e^x+1)$ and then cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Taylor series for $x \to 0$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{3x}-1}{e^x-1} = \frac{1 + 3x - 1 + \mathcal{O}(x^2)}{1 + x - 1 + \mathcal{O}(x^2)} = \frac{3x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)}{x + \mathcal{O}(x^2)} = 3 
$$